# Docker Alpine image, cannot find local network, connected to VPN

Tags: windows, docker, alpine-linux

I have two Docker images one Alpine, and one Ubuntu. When I want to connect to a host within a local network, connected via VPN. Only the Ubuntu image can connect.

First image

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
```

Second image

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/java/jdk:8-zulu-alpine
```

Connect via Ubuntu Docker image

```
telnet xxxx.xxxx.database.windows.net 1433
Trying 172.18.xx.xxx...
```

Connect via Alpine Docker image

```
telnet  xxxx.xxxx.database.windows.net 1433
telnet: can't connect to remote host (172.18.xx.xxx): Connection refused
```

Comment: Can you please share the output of `telnet localhost` and make sure you exposed the port within Docker File

Comment: bash-5.1# telnet localhost
telnet: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused , But in ubuntu some results